# Разблокировать экран android и вызвать activity при срабатывании будильника

Tags: android

Как разбудить android и вызвать activity когда сработает будильник? Прочитал про powerManager и wakelock но не совсем понял как их применить.

Answer (score 0):

Когда сработает будильник необходимо вызвать активити в моём случае таким образом

```
 Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, WakeUpActivity.class);
                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

а в самой активити указать следующее

```
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```